# How to combine exceptions to get rid of repeat code?

Tags: java, exception, space-efficiency

How can I minimize the repeated exception throwing code in the code:

```
public R get(int index) throws IndexException {
  if (!((0 <= index) && (index < this.info.length))) {
    throw new IndexException();
  }
  return this.info[index];
}

public void set(int index, R r) throws IndexException {
  if (!((0 <= index) && (index < this.info.length))) {
    throw new IndexException();
  }
  this.info[index] = r;
}
```

Comment: Why not put the checking code in a function of its own?

Comment: @Darkhogg's suggestion is a useful one, and follows the example of methods like [Object.requireNonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,%20java.lang.String)).  You also reduce cyclomatic complexity in this, because your get and set methods have fewer branches.

Comment: Also IMHO this should be an unchecked exception and you could reuse standard exceptions, such as `IndexOutOfBoundsException`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a method that will throw an exception:

```
private void checkBounds(int index) throws IndexException {
  if (index < 0 || index >= info.length) {
     throw new IndexException();
  }
}
```

You can then call it:

```
public R get(int index) throws IndexException {
  checkBounds(index);
  return this.info[index];
}

public void set(int index, R r) throws IndexException {
  checkBounds(index);
  this.info[index] = r;
}
```

Comment: oh, thanks! I didn't realize you could do that with exceptions.

Comment: `if (!((0 <= index) && (index < this.info.length)))` => `if (index < 0 || index >= info.length)` - trying to save a few brain cells...

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do, but I'd suggest to use an existing method:

```
 checkElementIndex(index, this.info.length)
```

from Guava's [Preconditions](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html).